# How to know that Admob ads banner is now showing or not due to resizable area?

Tags: java, android, admob, banner, adview

My application is resizable, sometimes my banner ads can't show due to Adview area is smaller 320x50dp. I want something like an event listener that calls me when the Adview has enough space to show or can't show the ads.

Comment: Have you tried looking into their API? https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ad-events. According to the link, there's an event `public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)` that will let you know if the Ad has failed to load which may or may not be what you're looking for. Always best if you look at the API and see if it has what you want. If not, there's not much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now event for this concern, you have to specify the minimum height, width to show the adds.